# Getting Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON in the hosted frontend react page

Tags: node.js, json, firebase, deployment, render

I'm running frontend on firebase and backend on render.

I set MY_BACKEND_URL to be the hosted backend server domain in the .env.process file of the frontend.

However, I'm getting Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON in the frontend console.

I don't get this error when I run the frontend locally.

Since everything works well when the frontend is running locally, I assume this error is occurring in app.js in the backend.

Here is my app.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
require("dotenv").config();

const articlesRoutes = require("./routes/articles-route");
const areasRoutes = require("./routes/areas-route");
const usersRoutes = require('./routes/users-route');
const commentsRoutes = require('./routes/comments-route');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth-routes');
const HttpError = require("./models/http-error");
const passportSetup = require('./config/passport-setup');

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(cookieSession({
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [process.env.COOKIE_SESSION_KEY]
}));


//initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({ 
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173', 
    credentials: true 
  }));
  

app.use('/uploads/images', express.static(path.join('uploads', 'images')));
app.use(express.static(path.join('public')));

// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:5173');
//     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
//     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
//     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); 
    
//     next();
// });

//set up routes
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/articles', articlesRoutes);
app.use('/api/areas', areasRoutes); 
app.use('/api/users', usersRoutes);
app.use('/api/comments', commentsRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

// app.use((req, res) => {
//     const error = new HttpError("Could not find this route.", 401);
//     throw error;
// });

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    if (req.file) {
        fs.unlink(req.file.path, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    if (res.headerSent) {
        return next(error);
    }
    res.status(error.code || 500);
    res.json({message: error.message || "An unknown error occurred."});
});

mongoose
    .connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@cluster0.roropup.mongodb.net/`)
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`The server is running on port ${port}.`);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

and this is the index.html file in 'dist' folder in the frontend.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-HKC4hwhc.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-oigOcOxM.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

*this is the index.html file outside of the dist folder in the frontend:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I copied the contents in the dist folder and pasted them down in the public folder in the backend.

What should I do to connect hosted frontend and backend?